# NhQueryable LINQ extension methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, c#-4.0, extension-methods, linq-to-nhibernate

**Solution**

I needed to update Nhibernate from version 3.1.0.4000 to 3.2.0.4000. My guess is that only 3.2+ has the extra Nhqueryable LINQ support. Btw, I am using NhQueryable because it appears to bind to JqGrid much faster that a regular IQueryable: better performance for JqGrid, hurrah!

**Original Issue**

Not sure my terminology or understanding is up to snuff to be able to ask this clearly:

I'm using asp.net, mvc3, and nhibernate(fluent). On one project I'm maintaining, I'm able to use LINQ extension methods (such as .Where()) with NhQueryable objects. On a second project, the only NhQueryable method available is .As<>().

What configuration/library/class am I missing in the second project? Nothing stands out to me in the first project where NhQueryable can use the LINQ extension methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that both projects are referencing the same version of NHibernate, one might be using an older version which does not have linq support.

If they are both using the same version, check that the correct namespaces have been added or you won't see the extension methods in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, that was the problem. I had checked the runtime versions of Nhibernate but not the actual .dll versions. Both runtimes were v2.0.50727. The .dll's, however, were different: 3.1.0.4000 vs. 3.2.0.4000. I updated the other project and it works.